# Cannot start matlab through spreadsheet link ex 3.2

Tags: excel, matlab, vba

I recently installed the spreadsheet link ex add-in on my excel 2013, but it doesn't work. When I try to choose the option 'Start MATLAB' from MATLAB field in HOME Ribbon it gives me an error:

'Cannot run the macro 'ribStartMatlab'. The Macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros all disabled.'

The same thing happens with any other MATLAB command chosen from excel.
I chose the option 'Enable all macros' in the Macro Security Settings and also checked the box 'Trust access to the VBA project object model'.

I also checked the SpreadsheetLink2007_2010 reference in the VBA->Tools->References (none other is available).

I found some information that the version of SP for Office might be put to blame but I checked and it seems I have the latest version of SP1 for Office 2013.

The exact name of the add-in is 'Spreadsheet Link EX 3.2 for use with MATLAB and Excel', the Office version is 2013 Proffesional Plus, and the MATLAB version is 2013b. Any help or tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is more of a guess than anything else. But I'm guessing the ribbon/macros use activeX control. at the end of last year there was an update to excel that disables activeX, which usually results in strange performance or code breaking with very cryptic error messages. It's a bit complicated to get it to work again, but here is a post that might provide some insight http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2015/03/11/forms-controls-stop-working-after-december-2014-updates-.aspx

again, this is really a guess, I don't know for certain the matlab commands use activeX but it's worth looking into